# Windsor - components and services added after resolving an item

Tags: wpf, castle-windsor

I am using the latest Castle Windsor in my WPF project and i encountered a really strange issue.

When resolving one of my ViewModels - the container self registers types that are not needed as services and injects empty properties of those types,
Is it common behavior for the container to self register services on it's own?

I can see that from checking the services collection of the Kernel after the configuring of the container, and i stopped just before one resolve, and 3 more services were added after the resolve was over...

If someone can shed some light on this issue that would be really helpful
Thanks

My Config file :

```
    public IContainerService Get()
    {
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        var adapter = new ContainerServiceWindsorAdapter(container.Kernel);

        container.Register(Component.For<IWindowManager>().ImplementedBy<TelerikWindowManager>());
        container.Register(Component.For<IEventAggregator>().ImplementedBy<EventAggregator>());
        container.Register(Component.For<INavigationService>().ImplementedBy<NavigationService>());
        container.Register(Component.For<IFileService>().ImplementedBy<FileService>());
        container.Register(Component.For<ISessionFactory>().UsingFactoryMethod(k =>
        {
            var fs = container.Resolve<IFileService>();
            var normalConfig = new Configuration().Configure(Path.Combine(fs.GetWorkingFolder(), CONFIG_FILE));

            return Fluently.Configure(normalConfig)
                           .CurrentSessionContext<ThreadStaticSessionContext>()
                           .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<NHDataAccessProvider>())
                           .ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema)
                           .BuildSessionFactory();
        }));
        container.Register(Component.For<IDataAccessProvider>().ImplementedBy<NHDataAccessProvider>());

        //Register IShell
        container.Register(Component.For<IShell>().ImplementedBy<ShellViewModel>()
            .Properties(p => p.PropertyType != typeof(IModuleDataScreen)));

        //Register all IModuleDataScreens
        container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssemblyContaining<ShellViewModel>()
                     .BasedOn(typeof(IModuleDataScreen))
                     .WithService.FromInterface(typeof(IModuleDataScreen))
                     .Configure(x => x.LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Transient))
                     .Configure(x => x.Named(x.Implementation.Name)));

        //Register all Modules
        container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssemblyContaining<ShellViewModel>()
                .BasedOn(typeof(IModule))
                .WithService.FromInterface(typeof(IModule))
                .Configure(x => x.LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Singleton))
                .Configure(x => x.Named(x.Implementation.Name)));


        container.Install(new CommonComponentsInstaller(),new DynamicCalculationsInstaller());

        var sf = container.Resolve<ISessionFactory>();
        CurrentSessionContext.Bind(sf.OpenSession());

        return adapter;
    }

public class DynamicCalculationsInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(Castle.Windsor.IWindsorContainer container, Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Configuration.IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Component.For<IFormulaEvaluator>().ImplementedBy<FleeFormulaEvaluator>().LifeStyle.Singleton);
        container.Register(Component.For<IRulesEvaluator>().ImplementedBy<FleeRulesEvaluator>().LifeStyle.Singleton);

        container.Register(Component.For<IPlansModule>()
                                    .ImplementedBy<PlansModule>()
                                    .LifeStyle
                                    .Transient);

        container.Register(
            Component.For<IDataProvider<PackageData>>()
                     .ImplementedBy<PackageDataProvider>()
                     .LifeStyle
                     .Transient);

        container.Register(Component.For<IPackagesModule>()
                                    .ImplementedBy<PackagesModule>()
                                    .LifeStyle
                                    .Transient);

        container.Register(Component.For<ExternalRuleSetService>());
    }
}

public class CommonComponentsInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{

    #region Implementation of IWindsorInstaller

    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Component.For<IErrorHandler>().ImplementedBy<ErrorHandlerEntLibAdapter>());
        container.Register(Component.For<ICacheService>().ImplementedBy<CacheServiceEntLibAdapter>());
        container.Register(Component.For<ILogger>().ImplementedBy<LoggerEntLibAdapter>());
        container.Register(Component.For<IMessageSerializer>().ImplementedBy<MessageSerializer>());
        container.Register(Component.For<IInteroperableSerializer>().ImplementedBy<InteroperableSerializer>());
        container.Register(Component.For<ILazyComponentLoader>().ImplementedBy<ConcreteClassComponentLoader>().Named("concreteClass"));
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Comment: showing your config might help and the examples you're talking about might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature you're referring to is called `ILazyComponentLoader`s.

It's an extension point where Windsor allows a component to be registered on the spot where it is required.

Windsor itself uses this in few places, the one most commonly used being [delegate-based typed factories](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-delegate-based-factories.ashx).

Now, to the solution. If you don't want Windsor to satisfy those dependencies, don't expose them to the container.

```
Container.Register(
    Component.For<MyType>().Properties(PropertyFilter.IgnoreAll));
   );
```

Comment: This will solve my problem partly, because i do have properties i want injected, and i want it to inject only the properties with contracts that i already registered, with your solution anytime i make a new property i want injected i will have to deal with the definitions. can i tell Windsor to inject only the properties that i have contracts for?